# How do I obtain the count of populated children in a Mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB and Mongoose.

Is there any simple way to get count of answers for each topic after population method?

```
var query = Topic.find({});
query.select("title answersRef");
query.populate({path:"answersRef", select:"_id"}); //here I want count of answers 

query.exec(function(topicError, topicResult){
    res.render('topic', { topic: topicResult });
});
```

On a webpage, I would like to show every topic's title that I find from database with the number of comments on each topic.

Comment: A point to consider here is that as long as the referenced object has not been deleted then the populated count is exactly the same as the number of "referenced" stored in the array prior to population. It can only be less if the referenced objects no longer exist in the target collection. The way mongoose stores these references, it is not possible for a single reference to expand into any more than one object per reference. Also if you are only selecting the `_id`, then there is little point in calling `.populate()`, since that is what is already stored in the main object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `answersRef` property of the `topicResult` contains all the answers so you can just obtain the length:

```
query.exec(function(topicError, topicResult){
    var answerCount = topicResult.answerRef.length;
    res.render('topic', { topic: topicResult });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my begineer's question!